# Toggle between warning and error in python

Tags: python, error-handling, warnings

Suppose I have a function that does a number of checks on the incoming values.

Normally violations would result in warnings to the user, the user would notice and correct accordingly. This would need to be adjustable by optional input, and therefore either error out or warn based on the parameter.

The snippet below would just result in the creation of a `TypeError` object, given that it would needs to be raised.

```
def is_even(a: int, on_error: Literal["warn", "error"] = "warn") -> bool:
    error_handler = ValueError if on_error == 'error' else warnings.warn
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        error_handler(f"{a=} is not an even number.")
        return False
```

Is there a way to either assign the raise `TypeError` to a variable, or to raise a warning without exiting the function?

Given the amount of checks in the function, the assignment would improve readability considerably, given that it avoids if-else statements on every check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
def is_even(a: int, on_error: Literal["warn", "error"] = "warn") -> bool:
    try:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"{a=} is not an even number.")
   
        ... < other checks that will also raise ValueError if not passed>

    except ValueError as ex:
        if on_error == 'error':
            raise
        else:
            warnings.warn(str(ex))
            return False
```

Note the empty `raise` statement in the `except` block reraises the same exception.

Another solution closer to what you've tried is:

```
def is_even(a: int, on_error: Literal["warn", "error"] = "warn") -> bool:
    def raise_error(m):
        raise ValueError(m)

    error_handler = raise_error if on_error == 'error' else warnings.warn
    
    if a % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        error_handler(f"{a=} is not an even number.")
        return False
```